# ReactJS: Why does pushing values to state in an object removes data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have set up a couple of input fields where the value goes into an object `input`, and I'm trying to store it into a new object with other data, but the value is disappearing.

On my `handleSubmit` function, I have `setNewData(mediaArray)` where it just sets the mediaArray into a new state - which it happens to be working correctly, but if I wrap the mediaArray into an object: `setNewData({mediaArray})`, it erases the data. Why does it do that?

I'm ultimately trying to do this: `setNewData({...setSomeOtherInfo, mediaArray})` so I can have this:

```
newData = {
  info: '',
  description: '',
  mediaArray: [
    {
      input1: '',
      input2: '',  
    },
    {
      input1: '',
      input2: '',  
    },
    {
      input1: '',
      input2: '',  
    },
  ]
}
```

Component:

```
const Screen = props => {

  const [someOtherInfo, setSomeOtherInfo] = useState({
    info: '',
    description: ''
  });
  const [mediaArray, setMediaArray] = useState([]);
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState(null);
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    input1: '',
    input2: ''
  });

  const handleInput1 = (index, value) => {
    mediaArray[index] = {
      ...mediaArray[index],
      ['input1']: value,
    };
  };

  const handleInput2 = (index, value) => {
    mediaArray[index] = {
      ...mediaArray[index],
      ['input2']: value,
    };
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setNewData(mediaArray);
  };

  useEffect(() => {

  }, [newData]);

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput onChangeText={e => handleInput1(index, e)} value={input.input1} />
      <TextInput onChangeText={e => handleInput2(index, e)} value={input.input2} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Screen;
```

Comment: It appears to me that you are probably trying to nest states. May be you could try without the nesting.

Comment: You're not using React the way it is designed to be used. You're mutating state. Use the `setState` functions instead of the assignment operator (`=`).

Comment: can you explain what is `index` in `handleInput1(index, e)` and `handleInput2(index, e)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it quite wrong.

1. You should not create so many states, if they are linked together. You can create a single state and update multiple values.
2. You cant setState with mutated data. You have to clone it before set again. Use destructure to clone

The sample is given below:

```
const Screen = props => {
  const [mediaArray, setMediaArray] = useState([]);
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState(null);
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    input1: "",
    input2: ""
  });

  const handleSubmit = (name, value) => {
    mediaArray[index] = {
      ...mediaArray[index],
      [name]: value
    };
    setMediaArray(mediaArray);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={e => handleSubmit.bind(null, 'input1')(index, e)}
        value={input.input1}
      />
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={e => handleSubmit.bind(null, 'input2')(index, e)}
        value={input.input2}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Screen;
```

If you have such complex logic. Create a reducer(use reducer) to make it simple.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you should try to use set methods for those states, instead of directly mutating the state.

```js
mediaArray[index] = {
      ...mediaArray[index],
      ['input1']: value,
    };
// instead of using this, try 
   setMediaArray((state) => {
      state[index].input1 = value
      return state
   })
```

I am not used to with functional component but as per normal scenario, this should work.